# Gatling Parameter value is getting Print in some unknown format

Tags: java, scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I am running below Script which is running fine in Gatling However its printing in format of some(value) and I am not getting why.it should print like 123456 but its printing some(123456)

```
def Getdata() = {
val jdbcFeeder1=jdbcFeeder(dbConnectionString,dbUserName,dbUserPassword,targetQuery)
val outputFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/gatling/resources/data/createddata.dat"
scenario("Write data To file")
  .repeat(1) {
    feed(jdbcFeeder1)
      .exec { session =>
        val writer1 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath, true))
        writer1.write(session.attributes.get("user_id").toString + "\n")
        writer1.close();
        session
      }
  }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> session.attributes.get("user_id").toString

You should be using the Session API correctly, please check the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/session_api/#getting-attributes).